# Starting the Java HPROF profiler on-the-fly programmatically

Tags: java, profiler, hprof

I am trying to selectively monitor/profile a Java application when certain runtime conditions are met. I am already able to dump the heap on-the-fly using the [HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html), which has been quite useful.

I am now trying to do something similar with CPU profiling, hoping to more effectively target specific code paths. I have some experience with the command-line [HPROF interface](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/raw-file/tip/src/share/demo/jvmti/hprof/manual.html) and the NetBeans profiler, but both need to be started beforehand.

Is there a way to activate the HPROF profiler programatically from within a running application? Preferably something that would allow me to start and stop the profiling process at will?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JVMTI documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html#onload), native agent libraries like hprof must be loaded very early during the JVM initialization, before any bytecode is executed.  So no, it is not possible to do this on-the-fly.

An alternative could be to re-launch the java process with modified JVM parameters within the main function, although this is not trivial.

Comment: Sadly, this seems to be the right answer, at least as far as HPROF is concerned... +1

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a good answer. It depends on more precisely what the original question is addressing. The cited documentation says the profiling agent must start before the JVM executes any code... it _does not_ say that the profiling must begin before code starts executing. The profiler can start and the _profiling_ can start later. A programmatic way to control when profiling starts would be very useful. Can you say that _profiling_ must start before any code executes? And cite a reference?